# What is a draw from a Dirichlet Process?

Tags: sample, dirichlet-distribution, dirichlet-process

I know a draw from a K-D Dirichlet distribution is a probability vector of dimension K. But still it's not clear what is a draw from a Dirichlet Process. What I understood is that a draw from a Dirichlet Process is a partitioning of a space of data points AND a probability measure over this partitioning. In other words, I supposed Dirichlet Process is a distribution over all possible probability measures that can be defined over a space of data points.

Comment: What do you mean by K-D?

Comment: @ccsv K-dimensional

Comment: You said it yourself: each draw is a discrete probability distribution

Comment: @ssdecontrol that is for Dirichlet distribution and not Dirichlet Process. In fact, the purpose of my question is to understand what is a draw from Dirichlet Process. I already know what is a draw from Dirichlet Distribution.

Comment: Whoops, not reading carefully. It's even in the title!

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to understand the sample from DP in such a way:
What you draw from k-d dirichlet is a discrete distribution of k elements. You might 
get a vector of k non-zero elements or k'< k non-zeros elements. It means you can draw a k'<=k dim discrete distribution from direchlet. However, we want to draw a arbitrary dimension discrete distrituion. "DP" helps you to do that by giving you a infinite dimension vector with k'< inf non-zero elements, which is (arbitrary) k' dim discrete distribution. Such a discrete distribution is a actually a partition of measure [0,1]. The real DP (not "DP") can do better, it generate a partition of arbitrary probabilistic measure specified by the base measure M of DP(M,a).

Comment: This is actually a very nice explanation of how the infiniteness of the dimensionality of the draw helps. However, I wonder if we actually draw from DP. My understanding so far is that DP guarantees that any partitioning of a space will can be assigned a probability measure function. So, there will exist a valid Dirichlet distribution that this partitioning be a draw from it.

Comment: @user3639557 Can't we implement the algorithm described in the [Introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_process#Introduction)?  And we can use a truncated version, that is, stop when $n>>\alpha$. And we can obtain a frequency based discrete probability.